# What language is used in apache files?

Tags: apache, scripting-language

What is the name of the language used in apache files like httpd.conf and virtual hosts e.g.

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably greatest highlighting setups for IDE (if you mean that purpose) are:

- **Tcl** for *.conf* files
- **Lisp** for *.ini* files

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html) refers to them as "httpd configuration file" or just "configuration file". I don't think there is a more specific name than that.